# How to create new columns from existing column which contains a list of dictionaries in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark

I have the following PySpark DataFrame which in real has thousands of records. I need to create new columns from the the data in the trans column.

| id | trans |
| --- | --- |
| 06t84g | [{'group': [{'sub': '24234234', 'pCode':'kZip', 'dtl':['CLIENT'], 'reas':['ZYD']}], 'description': 'This is a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'Z'}] |
| 098t1g | [{'group': [{'sub': '24114234', 'pCode':'zZip', 'dtl':['REP'], 'reas':['XCD']}], 'description': 'This is not a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'Y'}] |
| 03z94f | [{'group': [{'sub': '00034274', 'pCode':'jZip', 'dtl':['REP'], 'reas':['KYD']}], 'description': 'This is a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'M'}] |
| 10yw22 | [{'group': [{'sub': '11114234', 'pCode':'nZip', 'dtl':['CLIENT'], 'reas':['VVD']}], 'description': 'This is a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'V'}] |
| 30r990 | [{'group': [{'sub': '999994', 'pCode':'bZip', 'dtl':['CLIENT'], 'reas':['BYD']}], 'description': 'This is a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'B'}] |

I would like to create new columns out of the trans column just like the example below:

| id | sub | pCode | dtl | reas | description | DType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06t84g | 24234234 | kZip | ['CLIENT'] | 0.77 | This is a successful test, we have the results | Z |
| 098t1g | 24114234 | zZip | ['REP'] | 0.137 | This is not a successful test, we have the results | Y |
| 03z94f | 00034274 | jZip | ['REP'] | 0.317 | This is a successful test, we have the results | M |
| 10yw22 | 11114234 | nZip | ['CLIENT'] | 0.457 | This is a successful test, we have the results | V |
| 30r990 | 999994 | bZip | ['CLIENT'] | 0.947 | This is a successful test, we have the results | B |

Comment: Is the schema for `trans` column gonna be fixed?

Comment: Please add to the question this result of your df: `df.printSchema()`

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to achieve almost all the columns in the format you need would be to leverage `from_json` and `explode` function.

Note: `reas` value was different from your output, please feel to change accordingly.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType,StringType,StructField,StructType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


# Reading a tsv file:sample.tsv
"""
id  trans
06t84g  "[{'group': [{'sub': '24234234', 'pCode':'kZip', 'dtl':['CLIENT'], 'reas':['ZYD']}], 'description': 'This is a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'Z'}]"
098t1g  "[{'group': [{'sub': '24114234', 'pCode':'zZip', 'dtl':['REP'], 'reas':['XCD']}], 'description': 'This is not a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'Y'}]"
03z94f  "[{'group': [{'sub': '00034274', 'pCode':'jZip', 'dtl':['REP'], 'reas':['KYD']}], 'description': 'This is a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'M'}]"
10yw22  "[{'group': [{'sub': '11114234', 'pCode':'nZip', 'dtl':['CLIENT'], 'reas':['VVD']}], 'description': 'This is a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'V'}]"
30r990  "[{'group': [{'sub': '999994', 'pCode':'bZip', 'dtl':['CLIENT'], 'reas':['BYD']}], 'description': 'This is a successful test, we have the results', 'DType':'B'}]"
"""
df = spark.read.csv('./sample.tsv',header=True,sep=r"\t")

# Define the nested schema's.

single_arr_schema=ArrayType(StringType(),True)
group_schema=StructType([
    StructField("sub",StringType(),True),
    StructField("pCode",StringType(),True),
    StructField("dtl",single_arr_schema,True),
    StructField("reas",single_arr_schema,True)
])
single_schema=StructType([
    StructField("group",ArrayType(group_schema,False),False),
    StructField("description",StringType(),True),
    StructField("DType",StringType(),True),
]
)
trans_schema=ArrayType(single_schema,False)

final_df=df.select(F.col("id"),F.from_json("trans",trans_schema).alias("value")).select("id",F.explode("value").alias("value")).select("id","value.*").select("*",F.explode(F.col("group"))).select("*","col.*").drop("group","col")

final_df.show()
```

Output:

```
>>> final_df.show()
+------+--------------------+-----+--------+-----+--------+-----+
|    id|         description|DType|     sub|pCode|     dtl| reas|
+------+--------------------+-----+--------+-----+--------+-----+
|06t84g|This is a success...|    Z|24234234| kZip|[CLIENT]|[ZYD]|
|098t1g|This is not a suc...|    Y|24114234| zZip|   [REP]|[XCD]|
|03z94f|This is a success...|    M|00034274| jZip|   [REP]|[KYD]|
|10yw22|This is a success...|    V|11114234| nZip|[CLIENT]|[VVD]|
|30r990|This is a success...|    B|  999994| bZip|[CLIENT]|[BYD]|
+------+--------------------+-----+--------+-----+--------+-----+
```